Sum[] function not computing the sum
I have the following sum:
$$\sum _{y=0}^x \left(1-n^2! \left(n^2\right)^{-y} \mathcal{S}_y^{\left(n^2\right)}\right)$$
Which, in Wolfram language can be written as:
Sum[(1 - (n^2)^-y (n^2)! StirlingS2[y, n^2]),{y,0,Infinity}]

However, when I evaluate the expression, it outputs the input command as follows:

I think the Stirling number is causing the problem, but, how can I avoid such issue?

n appears only in the form n^2 in your sum so we can replace it with plain n and then investigate this sum, then if we found solution we can substitute back to n^2.
Table[Sum[(1 - (n)^-y (n)! StirlingS2[y, n]), {y, 0, Infinity}], {n, 1, 7}]

FindSequenceFunction[%, n] // FullSimplify
Table[%, {n, 1, 7}]

%%% == %


{1, 3, 11/2, 25/3, 137/12, 147/10, 363/20}

n HarmonicNumber[n]

{1, 3, 11/2, 25/3, 137/12, 147/10, 363/20}

True

So for your original sum the formula is n^2 HarmonicNumber[n^2]:
Table[n^2 HarmonicNumber[n^2], {n, 1, 7}]


{1, 25/3, 7129/280, 2436559/45045, 34052522467/356948592, 54801925434709/364655436600, 13881256687139135026631/63245806209101973600}


Mathematica 14.1 on Windows 10 finds this sum for small convrete values of n:
Table[Sum[(1 - (n^2)^-y (n^2)! StirlingS2[y, n^2]),
{y, 0, Infinity}], {n, 1, 5}]


{1, 25/3, 7129/280, 2436559/45045, Sum[1 - 992717442773183102976*25^(3 - y)*StirlingS2[y,  25], {y, 0, Infinity}]}

